# windows 8 password protected sharing - workgroup (confuse)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, network-shares, workgroup

I am not sure if this is the correct understanding and behavior in a workgroup.

- compA/folderA shared with user compA/userA

If password protected sharing is turn on in compA

1) when compB try to access compA/folderA,  compB will prompt to enter a username/password, and that credential will need to match the credential granted to folderA in order to access folderA - (e.g. userA) right ?

If password protected sharing is turn off in compA

2) when compB try to access compA/folderA, what will happen ?

if password protected sharing is turn off in compA, and compA/folderA is shared to everybody

3) what will happen if compB try to access compA/folderA
*(in scenario 3, i am not able to access folderA even it is shared to everybody)*

why - is it because i am logged on as a user in compB that doesn't exists in compA (but i thought the folder is shared to "everybody" and there is no password protected sharing already) ?

Answer (score 0):

workgroup name of compA and B must be the same
past that it becomes confusing b/c Windows sometimes takes time to figure itself out and u may experience different results depending on how long the systems r up.
But, I believe in order to log onto a system when password sharing is on u must use the id of a user on compA. When pw sharing is off and permissions r correct for Everybody, then everybody in the the same workgroup can access the share.
Homegroups works a little easier for the designated user folders.